# Creating chat login system with javascript/ php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
$(function() {
    $('.newMessage').hide();
    $('#messageBoxSignIn').click(function() {
        $('#username').focus();
    });
}) ;


$(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
    $('#signIn').click(function() {
        var username = $('#username').val();

        if (username == "" || username == "Enter Username") {
            $('.error').show();
            return false;
        }


        $('#messageBoxSignInForm').hide();
        $('.newMessage').show();

        var dataString = 'username=' + username;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "singinout.php",
            data: dataString, 
            success: function () {
                $('.user').html('<span>Welcome <span id="loggedUser">' + username + '</span>!</span> <a id="signOut" onclick="window.location.reload()">SIGN OUT</a>');
            }

            });

    });
})
```

My code for the javascript, I want to make it so when the user types in a username in the messageboxsignin, a "welcome (username)!" text would appear as well as the sign in button would be changed to sign out. But it doesn't work, the text doesn't appear and the button still appears as sign in.

HTML code:

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chatcss.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>


<title>4thebored</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="chatBox">
    <div class="user">
        <form name="signIn" action="" onsubmit="return false">
            <span class="error">Invalid Username</span>
            <input type="text" size="13px" name="username" id="username" value="Enter Username" onclick='document.signIn.username.value = ""' />
            <input type="submit" id="signIn" value="SIGN IN" />
            </form>
    </div>  

    <div class="main">
        <p>admin: *******</p>
    </div>


    <div class="messagebox">

    <form name="messageBoxSignInForm" id="messageBoxSignInForm" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="submit" id="messageBoxSignIn" value="Sign in to enter chat" />
    </form>

    <form name="newMessage" class="newMessage" action="" onsubmit="return false">

    <div class="left">
    <textarea name="newMessageContent" id="newMessageContent">Enter your message here</textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
    <input type="submit" id="newMessageSend" value="SEND" />
    </div>

    </form>

    </div>


</div>

<script src="signinout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please also paste your HTML code?

Comment: @user007 apologies, posted the html code

Comment: Edited the swear word from the question.

Comment: Your code seems to run fine without the AJAX part, so you probably need to check on the code inside `singinout.php`

Comment: are you sure the ajax request succeeds? try adding `error: function(error) {alert(error)}` to $.ajax call

Comment: Alternatively, check your browser's developers Network tab. For Google Chrome, push F12 to open devtools and check network tools there. Then click the button and see what the ajax page returns.